# GAM in JAGS with missing data

Tags: gam, jags, mgcv

I am trying to build a JAGS model that includes both cyclic smooths by week and covariate values that are estimated within the model. I can build a JAGS model that includes smooths using mgcv's jagam function and JAGS code to estimate covariates but I can't figure out how to combine them.

A scaled down version of my data includes a binomial response, week of the year, age, and observed male and female counts to calculate the sex ratio with missing values in both age and male/female counts.

```
data<-data.frame(y = rbinom(100,1,0.5), week = runif(100,1,52), age = floor(runif(100,1,10)), females=floor(runif(100,60,100)))
data$males<-floor(runif(100,1,data$females))

data$age[c(1,10,60)]<-NA
data$males[c(3,50,72)]<-NA
data$females[c(3,50,72)]<-NA
```

I can build a JAGS model with a cyclic smooth by week but it removes all observations with any missing data (which is the majority of my full data) and doesn't include uncertainty in the sex ratio.

```
library(mgcv)
data$sr<-data$males/data$females

jd<-jagam(y ~ s(week, bs = "cc", k = -1, by = age) +
            s(week, bs = "cc", k = -1, by = sr),
          data=data, file="model.file",family = binomial)
```

And the JAGS model that estimates missing values and uncertainty in the sex ratio (but no weekly smooths).

```
model<-function() {
  beta0 ~ dnorm(0, 0.1)
  beta_age ~ dnorm(0, 0.1)
  beta_sr ~ dnorm(0, 0.1)
  
  for(obs in 1:n_obs) {
    mu[obs] <- beta0 + 
      beta_age * age[obs] + 
      beta_sr * sr[obs] 
      
    eMu[obs] <- exp(mu[obs])
    p[obs] <- eMu[obs] / (1 + eMu[obs])
  }
  
  for (obs in 1:n_obs) {
    y[obs] ~ dbin(p[obs], 1)
  }
  
  ### Model for missing age
  for(obs in 1:n_obs){
    age[obs] ~ dnorm(age_mu, age_tau)
  }
  age_mu ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
  age_tau <- pow(age_sd, -2)
  age_sd ~ dunif(0, 100)
  
  ### Model for sex ratio
  for(obs in 1:n_obs){
    # Sex ratio
    males[obs] ~ dbinom(sr[obs], females[obs])
    # Model for missing counts
    females[obs] ~ dpois(females_lambda)
    sr[obs] ~ dbeta(sr_alpha, sr_beta)
  }
  sr_alpha ~ dunif(.0001, 100)
  sr_beta ~ dunif(0.0001, 100)
  females_lambda ~ dunif(0, 100)
}
```

Any suggestions for how to integrate the two would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!